# Инструкция по созданию бэкенда для Vue приложения по стеку: - GraphQL, Apollo, Nodejs, Express, нереалеционная база данных(данные в JSON формате?)

Tags: node.js, express, backend, graphql, apollo-client

Обращаюсь к backend-разработчикам, особенно к тем, кто использовал в работе нижеперечисленный стек.

Прошу помощи в написании небольшой инструкции по созданию бэкэнда для Vue приложения,  за оплату!
Выбран определённый стек:  GraphQL, Apollo, Nodejs, Express, нереалеционная база данных(данные в JSON формате)

Цель: Получить чёткое представление о направлении в создания бэкенд приложения.
Отправная точка – Vue приложение, созданное с помощью  Nuxt. Базы данных нет

Задача:

- По возможности схематично изобразить как по шагам создаётся бэкенд приложение, с учётом выбранного стека.
- Когда и с какой технологии начинаем приступать и почему? Какие она решает задачи? Почему мы её используем?

К примеру, я собираю знания по GraphQL, по немного выстраивая картину. Проблема часто бывает в том, что знания разрознены, а базы не хватает, чтобы провести связь о между ними.
https://prnt.sc/lF4wyWXP6E-h

Проблема в том, что ещё существует путаница(сейчас уже меньше но…) с пониманием GraphQL клиент, GraphQL сервер, Apollo клиент, Apollo сервер. Зачем нужен Apollo?
Или, пишут что сервер можно развернуть как  на  NodeJS,  так и на Express Apollo, GraphQL. Так где же его разворачивать? То же самое с созданием API. Я работал с готовыми API, созданием не занимался…. И так же пишут, что API можно создать с любой вышеперечисленной технологией. Так с помощью чего всё таки создавать? Материал по созданию JSON структуры приложения.

Как я вижу вашу итог помощи. Речь не идёт, что я рассчитываю обучиться этим технологиям с вашей помощью.  Нет! Речь о инструкции к действию. То есть, ваша, пусть краткое объяснение, должно помочь мне самому пойти дальше в бэкенд. Если ваше объяснение будет сопровождаться полезными ссылками, то это только плюс!

Пожалуйста, скажите сколько это будет стоить!

Comment: Серверная часть пишется не для Vue, React, JS и т.д., а просто для клиента, и не важно, как и на какой технологии клиентское приложение создано. На сервере реализуюется прием запросов от клиентской части(API) и отправки ответов. Простые АПИ можно поднять на nodejs + express минут за 10. Я бы вам рекомендовал пройти путь на маленьком приложении и попробовать, отдель попробовать прикутить apollo потом graphql(ну или наоборот) и выбрать удобный для себя стек

Comment: согласен. Это и хочу сделать. Проблема в том, что нужна небольшая инструкция, что как работает. И дальше я начну сам писать

Comment: Инструкцию можно сделать для конечного продукта(для электрочайника, допустим), а вот инструкцию по созданию электрочайника сделать не получится, т.к. каждый делает свое уникальное и только после создания, можно описать, как этим пользоваться. В вашем случае, читайте документацию и ищите примеры, кто что и как делал. Все примеры разные и какой из них больше вам подойдет, не известно. Вбейте в поисковик "создание сервера на nodejs + express", найдете несколько статей, пробуйте, экспериментируйте... Разработка, это не следование инструкциям, а творчество и фантазия в рамках документации )

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не по теме сообщества.